# Table pagination using jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have created a json table.For that I am trying to add pagination using plugin,This is the first time I am using plugin and I don't know how to combine table with pager.please give me some ideas.
I am using this plugin http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-Customizable-Pagination-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Twbs-Pagination.html

If there are any other methods to do it please suggest to me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
pagination()
window.pagObj = $('#pager').twbsPagination({
            itemsPerPage: 3,
            itemsContainer: ".myTable",
            // item: "> div",
            totalPages: 3,
            visiblePages: 2,
            onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                console.info(page + ' (from options)');
            }
        }).on('page', function (event, page) {
            console.info(page + ' (from event listening)');
        });
});
function pagination(){
    for(var i=0;i<userDetails.length;i++){
    var tab='<tr id="row'+i+'"><td>'+userDetails[i].Sno+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].empId+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Firstname+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].email+"\n"+'</td><td>'
              +userDetails[i].phone+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].designation+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].projectAllocated+"\n"+'</td><td><button class="btn btn-info edit" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal" data-html="true">'+
              userDetails[i].edit +'</button><button class="btn btn-warning  dlt">'+userDetails[i].remove +'</button></td></tr>';

     $('#myTable').append(tab);

}
}
```

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/4597shdo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Can use `paginga.jquery.min.js` plugin for simple pagination

```js
var userDetails=[
{
"Sno":"1",
"empId":"Emp001122",
"name":"john",
"email":"john@fusiongts.com",
"phone": "9876543210",
"designation":"designer",
"projectAllocated":"xxx",
"edit":"Edit",
"remove":"Delete"
},
{
"Sno":"2",
"empId":"Emp002233",
"name":"mano",
"email":"mano@fusiongts.com",
"phone": "9876543210",
"designation":"developer",
"projectAllocated":"yyy",
"edit":"Edit",
"remove":"Delete"
},
{
"Sno":"3",
"empId":"Emp002233",
"name":"mano",
"email":"mano@fusiongts.com",
"phone": "9876543210",
"designation":"developer",
"projectAllocated":"yyy",
"edit":"Edit",
"remove":"Delete"
},
{
"Sno":"4",
"empId":"Emp002233",
"name":"mano",
"email":"mano@fusiongts.com",
"phone": "9876543210",
"designation":"developer",
"projectAllocated":"yyy",
"edit":"Edit",
"remove":"Delete"
},
{
"Sno":"5",
"empId":"Emp002233",
"name":"mano",
"email":"mano@fusiongts.com",
"phone": "9876543210",
"designation":"developer",
"projectAllocated":"yyy",
"edit":"Edit",
"remove":"Delete"
},
{
"Sno":"6",
"empId":"Emp001144",
"name":"justin",
"email":"justin@fusiongts.com",
"phone": "9876543210",
"designation":"HR",
"projectAllocated":"zzz",
"edit":"Edit",
"remove":"Delete"
},
{
"Sno":"7",
"empId":"Emp001166",
"name":"guna",
"email":"guna@fusiongts.com",
"phone": "9876543210",
"designation":"designer",
"projectAllocated":"ggg",
"edit":"Edit",
"remove":"Delete"
},
{
"Sno":"8",
"empId":"Emp001122",
"name":"john",
"email":"john@fusiongts.com",
"phone": "9876543210",
"designation":"designer",
"projectAllocated":"xxx",
"edit":"Edit",
"remove":"Delete"
},
{
"Sno":"9",
"empId":"Emp002233",
"name":"mano",
"email":"mano@fusiongts.com",
"phone": "9876543210",
"designation":"developer",
"projectAllocated":"yyy",
"edit":"Edit",
"remove":"Delete"
}
];
$(document).ready(function(){
 pagination()
})
function pagination(){
    for(var i=0;i<userDetails.length;i++){
    var tab='<tr id="row'+i+'"><td>'+userDetails[i].Sno+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].empId+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Firstname+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].email+"\n"+'</td><td>'
              +userDetails[i].phone+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].designation+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].projectAllocated+"\n"+'</td><td><button class="btn btn-info edit" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal" data-html="true">'+
              userDetails[i].edit +'</button><button class="btn btn-warning  dlt">'+userDetails[i].remove +'</button></td></tr>';

     $('#content').append(tab);

}
}
```

```css
.pager div{
float: left;
border: 1px solid gray;
margin: 5px;
padding: 10px;
color: blue;
}
.pager div.disabled{
opacity: 0.25;
}
.pager .pageNumbers a{
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 10px;
color: blue; 
}
.pager .pageNumbers a.active{
color: orange;
}
.pager {
overflow: hidden;
}
.paginate-no-scroll .items div{
height: 250px;
}
tr,table,td,th{
border:1px solid #000;
padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/paginga.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="paginate 1" >
   <div class="items" id="content">
   </div>
   <div class="pager">
    <div class="firstPage">&laquo;</div>
    <div class="previousPage">&lsaquo;</div>
    <div class="pageNumbers"></div>
    <div class="nextPage">&rsaquo;</div>
    <div class="lastPage">&raquo;</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <script>
   $(function() {
    $(".paginate").paginga({
                 item: "> tr",
                 itemsPerPage: 5,
                 maxPageNumbers:3
    });
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```